# Sign in card prompt only one time after that their no more prompt of sign in card on any input from user to bot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I hava bot made using framework v4 using c#. It has been authenticated using azure ad. The first time i send user a message it prompt me with sign in prompt, but if i didn't sign in and the next time i send message to bot it doesnot prompt me sign in card again.I want that even if user doesnot sign in , the next time when user send a input to bot, the sign card should prompt again
The image in emulator 
[image]

**The code used for ad authentication*

```
public class MainDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    private readonly IBotServices _botServices;
    protected readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly UserState _userState;

    private readonly string _connectionName;

    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public MainDialog(IConfiguration configuration,ILogger<MainDialog> logger, IBotServices botServices)
        : base(nameof(MainDialog))
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
        _botServices = botServices ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(botServices));
        _connectionName = configuration["ConnectionName"];

        AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
          nameof(OAuthPrompt),
          new OAuthPromptSettings
          {
              ConnectionName = configuration["ConnectionName"],
              Text = "Please Sign In",
              Title = "Sign In",
              Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login (1000 * 60 * 5)
          }));

        AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(nameof(ConfirmPrompt)));

        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)));
        AddDialog(new luisandqnamakerDialog(_botServices,_configuration,_logger));
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            PromptStepAsync,
            LoginStepAsync             
        }));

        // The initial child Dialog to run.
        InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoginStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        // Get the token from the previous step. Note that we could also have gotten the
        // token directly from the prompt itself. There is an example of this in the next method.
        var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;
        if (tokenResponse != null)
        {
            if (IsAuthCodeStep(stepContext.Context.Activity.Text))
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You are now logged in."), cancellationToken);
                return await stepContext.NextAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                 await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(luisandqnamakerDialog), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Would you like to ask your question?") }, cancellationToken);
                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }
        }           

        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Login was not successful please try again."), cancellationToken);

        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }

    private bool IsAuthCodeStep(string code)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) || !code.Length.Equals(6)) return false;
        if (!int.TryParse(code, out int result)) return false;
        if (result > 1) return true;                
        return false;
    }


    protected override async Task<DialogTurnResult> OnBeginDialogAsync(DialogContext innerDc, object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var result = await InterruptAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
        if (result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }

        return await base.OnBeginDialogAsync(innerDc, options, cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task<DialogTurnResult> OnContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var result = await InterruptAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
        if (result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }

        return await base.OnContinueDialogAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InterruptAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        if (innerDc.Context.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            var text = innerDc.Context.Activity.Text.ToLowerInvariant();

            if (text == "logout")
            {
                // The bot adapter encapsulates the authentication processes.
                var botAdapter = (BotFrameworkAdapter)innerDc.Context.Adapter;
                await botAdapter.SignOutUserAsync(innerDc.Context, _connectionName, null, cancellationToken);
                await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You have been signed out."), cancellationToken);
                return await innerDc.CancelAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Isma is it fine now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to handle this is to just reprompt with text that tells the user to click the button that has already been sent. You can do this with the `RetryPrompt` property of `PromptOptions`. (Note that this will not work if the bot sends a typing activity.)

```
return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(
    nameof(OAuthPrompt),
    new PromptOptions
    {
        RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please click the sign-in button.")
    }, cancellationToken);
```

If you really want to reprompt with the whole card again then you have two options and they're both sort of complicated.

### Option 1: Create the card yourself

The actual card that the OAuth prompt uses is generated in a private method, so there's no way for you to call that code. You'll have to have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Prompts/OAuthPrompt.cs#L301-L372) and copy it for your own use:

> ```
> // Ensure prompt initialized
> if (prompt == null)
> {
>     prompt = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
> }
>
> if (prompt.Attachments == null)
> {
>     prompt.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
> }
>
> // Append appropriate card if missing
> if (!ChannelSupportsOAuthCard(turnContext.Activity.ChannelId))
> {
>     if (!prompt.Attachments.Any(a => a.Content is SigninCard))
>     {
>         var link = await adapter.GetOauthSignInLinkAsync(turnContext, _settings.OAuthAppCredentials, _settings.ConnectionName, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
>         prompt.Attachments.Add(new Attachment
>         {
>             ContentType = SigninCard.ContentType,
>             Content = new SigninCard
>             {
>                 Text = _settings.Text,
>                 Buttons = new[]
>                 {
>                     new CardAction
>                     {
>                         Title = _settings.Title,
>                         Value = link,
>                         Type = ActionTypes.Signin,
>                     },
>                 },
>             },
>         });
>     }
> }
> else if (!prompt.Attachments.Any(a => a.Content is OAuthCard))
> {
>     var cardActionType = ActionTypes.Signin;
>     string signInLink = null;
>
>     if (turnContext.Activity.IsFromStreamingConnection())
>     {
>         signInLink = await adapter.GetOauthSignInLinkAsync(turnContext, _settings.OAuthAppCredentials, _settings.ConnectionName, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
>     }
>     else if (turnContext.TurnState.Get<ClaimsIdentity>("BotIdentity") is ClaimsIdentity botIdentity && SkillValidation.IsSkillClaim(botIdentity.Claims))
>     {
>         // Force magic code for Skills (to be addressed in R8)
>         signInLink = await adapter.GetOauthSignInLinkAsync(turnContext, _settings.ConnectionName, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
>         cardActionType = ActionTypes.OpenUrl;
>     }
>
>     prompt.Attachments.Add(new Attachment
>     {
>         ContentType = OAuthCard.ContentType,
>         Content = new OAuthCard
>         {
>             Text = _settings.Text,
>             ConnectionName = _settings.ConnectionName,
>             Buttons = new[]
>             {
>                 new CardAction
>                 {
>                     Title = _settings.Title,
>                     Text = _settings.Text,
>                     Type = cardActionType,
>                     Value = signInLink
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

You'll notice that this code uses another private method called `ChannelSupportsOAuthCard`, and if the channel doesn't support OAuth cards then it uses a signin card instead. You haven't mentioned what channel you're using so I've included both cases here, but if you know that all the channels you're using do support OAuth cards then you can just use the OAuth card code. Alternatively, if you don't want any of your channels to use OAuth cards then you can just use the signin card code. Once you've created the activity with the card in it, you can use it for both the `Prompt` and the `RetryPrompt` properties of your prompt options:

```
return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(
    nameof(OAuthPrompt),
    new PromptOptions
    {
        Prompt = prompt,
        RetryPrompt = prompt
    }, cancellationToken);
```

### Option 2: Restart the dialog

If you really don't want to worry about creating the card yourself, the only way to use the builtin code for this purpose is to call `BeginDialogAsync` again. There are several ways to approach this but I'll try to go with the simplest route.

It looks like you already have some "try again" functionality in `LoginStepAsync` where you end the dialog and I presume whatever code you have calling the `MainDialog` will begin it again automatically on the next turn. If you don't want to wait for the next turn then you can use a little trick where you replace a dialog with itself:

```
await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Login was not successful please try again."), cancellationToken);

return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(nameof(WaterfallDialog), cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Of course, to get to the `LoginStepAsync` step you'll need a way to end the OAuth prompt when the user types something. You can do this by returning `true` from the prompt's validator:

```
AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
  nameof(OAuthPrompt),
  new OAuthPromptSettings
  {
      ConnectionName = configuration["ConnectionName"],
      Text = "Please Sign In",
      Title = "Sign In",
      Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login (1000 * 60 * 5)
  }, (_, _) => Task.FromResult(true)));
```

This example will make the prompt's validator always return `true` and so it will end the prompt on the next turn no matter what. If you want, you could put your own logic in the validator so that it checks the activity and the recognizer result and decides based on that. But once the prompt ends and the waterfall proceeds to the next step, `LoginStepAsync` will see a null token response and so it will know that it needs to restart the dialog.

Comment: @ Thanks Kyle Delaney for your help. Really help me alot

Comment: @AmitKumar - I'm glad. Please consider upvoting answers that help you.